# Git: Undo changes that were already published

Tags: git

So I have been regretting the last 3 commits I did on my project during this week. The problem is that I already pushed them to the public repository and I suspect at least a couple of people have pulled those changes.

What would be now the safest course of action to undo the changes in those last 3 commits, wituout giving any grievance to the people who pulled those changes?

Comment: Since reverted commits are _new_ commits, negating the effect of "bad" commits, you should revert them in reversed order to avoid/minimize possible commits

Comment: Means I have to do it one by one?

Comment: No? if you invoke something like this: `git revert HEAD~2..HEAD`, they are reverted in the correct order, from newest to oldest.

Answer (score 2):

In the end what did it was simple this:

```
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD
```

When I executed it, it created a new commit for each commit that I was reverting, undoing its changes. It would have been better if it would have reverted everything in one single commit. But that is good enough, I guess.

Comment: You could theoretically squash the revert commits using `git rebase -i` and use an appropriate commit message. Or you could do the same without `git revert` using `git checkout HEAD~3 .` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert to the state as of a particular commit, and really don't want a chain of reverts showing how it got there,

```
newcommit=$(
    git cat-file -p $thatcommit \
    | sed '1,/^$/d;$a \
             reverting to '$(git rev-parse $thatcommit) \
    | git commit-tree -p HEAD $thatcommit^{tree}
)
branch=`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`
git checkout ${branch:+-B $branch} $newcommit
```

will duplicate `$thatcommit` at your branch tip, message and all (only the new dates/parents, plus the "reverting" note at the end).

Answer (score 0):

You can just `git reset --hard` to the commit you want to be the tip, and `git push` (perhaps need to `--force` the non-fast-forward commit) the result.

But that means the changes are *lost forever*. Perhaps you should create a new branch at the tip (`git branch this-was-a-big-mistake`) before the above, and push out both branches...